# Hierarchical forecasting with user-defined function in R, arima with fourier terms

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I'm trying out top-down method for forecasting demand of products in a retail store.

```
fourier_forecasts = forecast(sales_weekly_hts, h=12,method="tdfp", FUN=function(x) auto.arima(x, xreg=fourier(x, K=12), seasonal=FALSE))
```

*sales_weekly_hts* is an *hts* object containing 2.5 years of weekly sales data.

It gives me the error :-

"***Error in forecast.Arima(models, h = h) : No regressors provided***"

I'm guessing that error is because its not able to obtain the fourier terms for out of sample forecast but I don't get how to resolve this.
Is it not able to know how many periods to forecast into the future?

Minimum reproducible example:-

```
library(dplyr)
library(hts)

# creating a time series matrix containing 4 series and 133 weeks random data 
min_rep_eg = matrix(data = rnorm(n = 133*4 ,mean = 2), nrow = 133, ncol = 4) %>% ts(frequency = 365.25/7)

# giving names to the 5 time series. These names are used to create the hierarchy.
colnames(min_rep_eg) = c("10011001","10011003","10031021","10031031")

# creating the hts.
min_rep_eg_hts = hts(min_rep_eg, characters = c(4, 4))

min_rep_eg_hts_fc = forecast(min_rep_eg_hts, h=2,method="tdfp", FUN=function(x) auto.arima(x, xreg=fourier(x, K=12), seasonal=FALSE))
```

Comment: Hi, please [provide data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), e.g. adding the output of `dput(<myData>)` or `dput(head(<myData>))` to your question. You'll have a much better chance of getting a great answer!

Comment: Maybe try to consider fewer Fourier terms (i.e. decrease `K`)? Lower `K` means less complexity of your seasonal pattern. By decreasing `K`, you decrease the frequency of sine and cosine pairs that your model uses to approximate the seasonal pattern.

Comment: Also, it may be worthwhile to check whether it makes lots of sense to forecast your sales data weekly - maybe monthly aggregates lead to less noise?

Comment: @jay.sf dput gives me a huge amount of output would be too much to paste here. I'll try to write more about the data.

Comment: @Luminita I chose a K value my minimized Aicc. Also model with relatively higher K value gives me visually more correct forecast. and as for your second question, I wanted to use monthly however I would end up with just 33 data points probably too less to make a good forecast. But I guess noise shouldn't be a problem in hierarchical forecasting, at higher levels of hierarchy I am able to discern seasonal patterns visually (it's still a bit noisy)

Comment: added a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

I just saw your post now. As your are using the `auto.arima` function, the easiest way to solve your problem is to use the arima model via the `fmethod` argument. Then, to set the value of external regressors via `xreg` and `newxreg`.

Taking your reproducible example :

```
library(dplyr)
library(hts)

# creating a time series matrix containing 4 series and 133 weeks random data 
min_rep_eg = matrix(data = rnorm(n = 133*4 ,mean = 2), nrow = 133, ncol = 4) %>% ts(frequency = 365.25/7)

# giving names to the 5 time series. These names are used to create the hierarchy.
colnames(min_rep_eg) = c("10011001","10011003","10031021","10031031")



# creating the hts.
min_rep_eg_hts = hts(min_rep_eg, characters = c(4, 4))
x=allts(min_rep_eg_hts)[,1]



min_rep_eg_hts_fc = forecast(min_rep_eg_hts, h=1,method="tdfp", fmethod ="arima",xreg=fourier(x, K=12),newxreg=tail(fourier(x, K=12),1))
```

Output :

[image]